# ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi WebView me redireccione a Google play?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play, webview-android

Resulta que tengo una WebView que está enlazada a un blog que sube post de tutoriales, las app que están en ese blog son de google play. Cuando intento descargar una no puedo, ya que no me redirecciona a la tienda de google.

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que la WebView me redireccione a Google Play cuando sea necesario?

Este es mi código:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView wv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.txt_Web);


        WebSettings webSettings = wv1.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        String URL = "http://sebatutoplays.com/";
        wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv1.loadUrl(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        WebView myWebView;
        if(wv1.canGoBack()){
            wv1.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
    }
`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes implementar el método [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) a tu `webView` que permite tratar los enlaces como tu quieras, devolviendo false si quieres que lo siga tratando tu `webView` o true si quieres que abandone el `webView` y trate el enlace por si mismo (lanzando el `intent` correspondiente asociado a ese link).

Por lo que puedes crear este método diciéndole que si la dirección web empieza por `https://play.google.com` o por `market://details?id=` lo trate el sistema directamente (por lo que lo abrirá con Google Play).

Esto debería servir para hacer lo que quieres:

```
wv1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest webResource) {
        if (webResource != null && (webResource.getUrl().toString().startsWith("https://play.google.com") || webResource.getUrl().toString().startsWith("market://details?id="))) {
            view.getContext().startActivity(
                    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webResource.getUrl()));
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

En android para abrir una url de aplicación desde Google Play Store, se puede la url :

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<paquete de aplicacion>
```

o mediante el protocolo `market://` :

```
market://details?id=id=<paquete de aplicacion>
```

por lo tanto puedes usar un Intent para realizar esta tarea usando la url:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<paquete de aplicacion>"));
startActivity(i);.
```

o usando `market://`

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=<paquete de aplicacion>"));
startActivity(i);
```

---

> ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que la WebView me redireccione a Google
>   Play cuando sea necesario?

Como ejemplo si tu url contiene la palabra `sebatutoplays` que redireccione a una aplicación:

```
private String word = "sebatutoplays";
private String myUrl= "";

       webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){


            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                    //Obtiene url
                    myUrl = request.getUrl().toString();

                }else{

                    //Obtiene url
                    myUrl = request.toString();

                }

              //si la url contiene la palabra abre Google Play Store.
              if(myUrl.contains(word)){
                Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<paquete de aplicacion>"));
                startActivity(i);.
              }


                return true;
            }


        });
```

Comment: **Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: no me a funcionado lo e intentado de muchas formas y asta ahora no e tenido éxito.

Comment: Si no has resuelto tu problema agrega que error tienes.